# RasterIO how to extract multiple shapes from geotiff rather than background

Tags: python, geojson, geotiff-tiff, rasterio

Im trying to convert my geotiff to GeoJson using rasterio, when I run the following code

```
with rasterio.open("../media/temp/temp.tif") as dataset:
    # Read the dataset's valid data mask as a ndarray.
    mask = dataset.dataset_mask()

    # Extract feature shapes and values from the array.
    for geom, val in rasterio.features.shapes(
           mask, transform=dataset.transform):

        # Transform shapes from the dataset's own coordinate
        # reference system to CRS84 (EPSG:4326).
        geom = rasterio.warp.transform_geom(
            dataset.crs, 'EPSG:4326', geom, precision=-1)

        return geom
```

I get one Geojson feature that is the background of my Geotiff with my data shapes cut out, its the opposite of what I'm looking for how can I get the shapes into a feature collection and leave out the background.

Comment: Multiple shapes: don't immediately break the loop with `return`.  Leave out the background: check `val` to determine what each geom represents

Comment: So I delete val and where do I add return?